# convert scientific data into generic

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have a file containing only numerical values in scientific format. I want to convert them into generic notation and multiply them by 1000. e.g.
*input.txt*

```
1.1234e-01  
2.123e+01  
3.12345e-02  
...  
...
```

*output.txt*

```
112.34  
21230  
31.2345  
...  
...
```

I have many such files to perform the task (one file at a time) so command line single liner solution is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this little awk script:

```
#!/bin/awk
{ printf "%f\n", 1000*$0 }
```

That's reasonably concise, but may produce unnecessary trailing zeroes.